# Constexpr constructor for a static variable results in dynamic initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr, static-variables, static-initialization

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void Init();

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        int *p = new int; // just to make sure Foo's ctor is not a constant expression
        Init();
    }
} foo;

struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar()
        : value(0) { }
    int value;
} bar;

void Init() {
    bar.value = 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bar.value << std::endl;
}
```

Here `foo`'s constructor is not a constant expression, so we'll have dynamic initialization of `foo`. But `bar`'s constructor seems to be a constant expression, so we'll have static initialization of `bar`. So, `bar`'s ctor must be called before `foo`'s one and we'll see `1` as output. And I observe such result for GCC 8.3.0 and Clang 8.0.0. But for Visual C++ actual output is `0` and when I debug the application, I see that `foo`'s dynamic initialization is made first and then `bar`'s dynamic initialization is made.

Is the behavior that I observe (`bar.value == 0`) valid according to C++ 17 standard?

I'm using C++ compiler version 19.16.27027.1 for x86 Debug build or Release build with ctor's marked with `__declspec(noinline)`.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with "static-variables" and mentioned "static variables" in the title? The keyword "static" does not appear in your question, so you have global variables, not static ones. (Besides the tag refers to static members of a class, not simply variables declared "static".)

Comment: `bar` is not a constant expression just because constructor is `constexpr`. Declare it as `constexpr Bar bar;`. This will ultimately make `bar.value = 1;` invalid

Answer (score 5):

> But `bar`'s constructor seems to be a constant expression, so we'll have static initialization of `bar`.

That is an incorrect uderstanding.

A `constexpr` constructor can be used to construct a non-`const` object too. When that happens, that object will be initialized using dynamic initialization. In your case, `bar` is a non-`const` object. Hence it make sense that it is initialized using dynamic initialization.

Changing your code to:

```
struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar()
        : value(0) { }
    int value;
};

constexpr Bar bar;
```

should change initialization of `bar` to static initialization.

However, if `bar` is changed to a `const` object, you won't be be able to use

```
bar.value = 1;
```

in `Init()`. I just wanted to point out how to change `bar` so it can be initialized during static initialization.

Comment: So then the order in which `foo`  and `bar` are instantiated is dictated by the order in which they're declared, right? Does that mean it's technically UB that `Foo()` causes a write to `bar.value` even though `bar` hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: @lubgr, very much so.

Comment: From  [basic.static.start]/2: _"A constant initializer for a variable or temporary object o is an initializer whose full-expression is a constant expression, except that if o is an object, such an initializer may also invoke constexpr constructors for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types ... Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity"_. What am I missing?

Comment: @undermind, which version of the language is that from? C++14, C++17?

Comment: It's from C++17 working draft. In C++14 working draft we have another wording, but, imho, with the similar meaning: _A constant initializer for an object o is an expression that is a constant expression, except that it may also invoke constexpr constructors for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types... Constant initialization is performed: ... if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constructor call, and if the initialization full-expression is a constant initializer for the object_

Comment: @undermind, thanks. I am not a language lawyer. I will have to shift through the details to make sense of it in non-language-lawyer speak :)

Comment: Me too :) But from non-language-lawyer point of view: what prevents compiler to initialize `bar` at compile time, if it's ctor is `constexpr`?

Comment: @undermind, it's not clear to me whether the compiler is required to do so or is that an option for the compiler.

Comment: Ok, yes, it may be just an option. But anyway, what is the difference between `const Bar` and `Bar`, that makes it possible to perform constant initialization in the const-case but not in non-const?

Comment: @undermind, now that I think about it, that might not be sufficient. `constexpr Bar bar;` will probably force "constant initialization"